# Figure dimension output chunk options work in R markdown but not Quarto in RStudio

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio, quarto

In an RStudio R markdown document, to control the dimensions of figures previewed inline, the knitr code execution chunk options `fig.height` and `fig.width` can be set. The below example shows what this looks like for a 3 inch by 3 inch plot.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
date: "2023-07-12"
---

```{r, fig.height=3, fig.width=3}
plot(pressure)
box("figure")
```
````

[image: 3x3 plot]

However, this doesn't work when using the equivalent code execution code chunk options in an RStudio Quarto document. The plot is previewed inline at the default dimensions when the expectation is the plot should resemble the same 3 inch by 3 inch plot produced by the R markdown document.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
format: html
---

```{r}
#| fig-height: 3
#| fig-width: 3

plot(pressure)
box("figure")
```
````

[image: default dimensions plot]

Is this due to improper use of Quarto chunk options, or are the R markdown and Quarto document chunk options inconsistent in how they should be used, or is this a bug in Quarto chunk options?

Comment: This seems to be a bug in RStudio.  See [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/does-figure-size-in-quarto-qmd-documents-in-rstudio-need-to-be-specified-twice/158661). Sorry, but I don’t have the time to find the issue on the GitHub repo.

Comment: You can fortunately still use the "old" way in quarto: `{r, fig.height=3, fig.width=3}` should work.

Comment: On GitHub, see RStudio issues [11708](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/11708) and [12305](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/12305).